Is there a way to omit the last digit from the StopWatchWidget timer?
I have a StopWatchWidget in my app, and I have used it to create my own timer. It counts upwards, including minutes, seconds, and milliseconds. The issue is that the milliseconds take up 3 digits, whilst I want them to only take up 2 digits. How can I omit the last digit? I have attached an image, if it helps to get my point across: 
Here is my code:
class StopWatchWidgetState extends State<StopWatchWidget> {
  late Color timercolor = Colors.white;
  final Stopwatch _stopwatch = Stopwatch();
  String stopWatchText = '0.00.00';
  void startStopWatch() {
    if (_stopwatch.isRunning) {
      stopWatchText = "0.00.00";
      _stopwatch.stop();
    } else {
      stopWatchText = '0.00.00';
      _stopwatch
        ..reset()
        ..start();
    }

    Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        if (!_stopwatch.isRunning) {
          timer.cancel();
        }
        stopWatchText =
            '${(_stopwatch.elapsed.inMinutes % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '')}.${(_stopwatch.elapsed.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}.${(_stopwatch.elapsed.inMilliseconds % 1000).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';


Try this way
stopWatchText =
    '${(_stopwatch.elapsed.inMinutes % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '')}.${(_stopwatch.elapsed.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}.${(_stopwatch.elapsed.inMilliseconds % 1000 ~/ 100).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';


Yes, I have, both by 10, which does not work, and 100, but then the milliseconds do not count properly. For example, it will go over the digit '70' multiple times per second. I have found the only way to get them to accuratly count is to divide them by 1000.

Check my new edit above

Thank you! I made it work by changing 2 things from your answer: 1: It should be ~/100, not ~/10, and 2: You need to put the ~/100 right beside the %1000, not outside the parenthesis, if that makes sense.

Great! I am glad that I helped you. ⊂◉‿◉つ

You should change your post to what I have suggested, so that I can mark it as the correct answer.

This is what we achieved to fix the issue, right? Or am I missing something in the code?

Yes, the edited code works perfectly. Edit: Sorry, change the ~/100 back to ~/10, my mistake.
